# How to track dependency management file responsible for artifact version

Tags: maven

My question refers to bug https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/issues/265

Spring parent declares in dependency management mockito:5.3.1
My project is child of Spring parent and also has mockito:5.3.1

But my project imports dependency from spring-cloud-dependencies:2022.0.3

spring-cloud-dependencies use spring-cloud-kubernetes-dependencies which defines mockito:4.8.1

Finally, although my project is not related to kubernetes, mockito version is 4.8.1:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.mockito
...
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.8.1:test
[INFO]    \- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.8.1:test
```

Is it possible with other command or other plugin see something like:

```
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.8.1:test (from spring-cloud-kubernetes-dependencies)
```

Comment: You can overwrite that via defining the mockito-bom in your dependencyManagement ....